# Calculating spearman's rank correlation very quickly

Tags: concurrency, correlation

Is there a way of calculating [spearman's rank correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) over a large set of data very quickly. We have several thousand such calculations to perform every month and the total duration of these calculations takes far too long. Is it possible to perform spearman's rank correlation using concurrent (threads) operations, or to distribute the calculation across several cores (or servers even)?

Answer (score 0):

For Java developers Apache common ( org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.SpearmansCorrelation ) have now a class to calculate SpearmanCorrelation.